# Flutter Firebase query a collection while querying another collection

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My goal is iterate the "courses" collection, for each "course" i want to iterate the "\users\user@test.com\courses" collection and check if the user has made the course.

My idea is that (see the code above) but not finding the solution:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: getListCourses(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return FutureBuilder(
              future: getCoursesUser(snapshot.data?[index]["id"]),
              builder: (context2, snapshot2) {
                if (snapshot2.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context2, index2) {
                      return Text(snapshot2.data?[index2]["status"]);
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text("error");
                }
              },
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

The Future calls are:

```
Future<List> getListCourses() async {
  List objetoList1 = [];
  Query<Map<String, dynamic>> collectionReferenceObjetoList1 =
      db.collection('/courses').where("id", isNotEqualTo: "").orderBy("id");
  QuerySnapshot queryObjetoList1 = await collectionReferenceObjetoList1.get();
  queryObjetoList1.docs.forEach((documento) {
    objetoList1.add(documento.data());
  });

  return objetoList1;
}

Future getCoursesUser(String idCourse) async {
  final document =
      await db.collection("/users/user@test.com/courses").doc(idCourse).get();
  return document;
}
```

The list should show a "checked icon" if the course is done:

**Image:**

[image]

Then, i would like to understand if any way query multiple collections in Flutter Firebase by this way, or any best practices or suggestions.